# Upload a video to play and detect faces and emotions simultaneously using openCV in web application

Tags: python, opencv, web-applications

I need to upload a Video file in a browser and play it using HTML5 video player.

Simultaneously, I need to detect the faces and its emotion in **a frame that's currently playing** and display them below the video.

What is the best way go about detecting faces and emotions in every frame while playing the video?

Specifically need help in connecting the front end(browser) and server part(code to detect face and emotion)

1. Upon playing, fetch every frame through javascript, send to backend Python code and get a result image (doubt it will be very slow). If so, what framework would be useful?
2. use client side openCV framework to achieve this(opencv.js). Do recommend other good libraries to achieve if any.